# Does a `WHERE IN` statement optimize out duplicate values?

Tags: mysql

If I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id IN (1, 2, 2);
```

How will mysql process this?

My assumption is it will optimize out the duplicate `2` values and instead rework the query to be:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It will also convert the list into sorted and unique values before performing search

Comment: Read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in